# php Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I have a function which I created to return all fields of a row. However, it returns the following error.

`Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in`

My Code

```
function returnAllData($table, $field, $value){
  global $pdo;

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field = :val");
  $stmt-> bindValue(':val', $value);
  $stmt-> execute();
  $f = $stmt->fetch();
}
$memData = returnAllData('members', 'mem_id', userId());
echo $memData['mem_phone'];
```

I checked again and again but I could not get what actually is wrong with the code.

Comment: You forgot to say which line is generating the error.

Comment: of course, the echo line is obvious to return an error here. however, the problem is now solved. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to return the result from the `fetch()` call. Try this:

```
function returnAllData($table, $field, $value){
  global $pdo;

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field = :val");
  $stmt-> bindValue(':val', $value);
  $stmt-> execute();
  $f = $stmt->fetch();
  return $f;
}
$memData = returnAllData('members', 'mem_id', userId());
echo $memData['mem_phone'];
```